# XMLHttpRequest fail to open on firefox

Tags: javascript, ajax, firefox

When I try to open a XMLHttpRequest to a specific URL I get an error with no debugging information the request works with no errors on google chrome.

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
try {
  xmlhttp.open('GET', "http://172.17.1.33:8080/divbanco/threadsjson.jsp");
  console.log('Success');
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err);
  console.log(xmlhttp);
}
```

I'm running that from 172.17.1.41 so I don't think it's a cross-domain call error. Also requests to http://172.17.1.35:8080/divbanco/threadsjson.jsp succeed. The URL exists too, it returns a JSON object: http://pastebin.com/m58fu4E4

Comment: `172.17.1.41 !== 172.17.1.33`, so it is in fact cross-domain. but that doesn't mean it's a cross-domain error. Cross domain errors are usually very obvious in the error/network consoles.

Comment: the json you pasted in pastebin seems to fail jsonlint validation due to a newline char. but... that shouldn't be causing your request to fail, you aren't even parsing it yet.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My bad! Noscript was blocking my request to 172.17.1.33. I forgot that I had to allow requests to the other URL's at a previous date. Disabling the active plugins allowed me to see that problem.

Answer (score 0):

inrelevant but, Just want to say that new fetch API is out there.

```
fetch("http://172.17.1.33:8080/divbanco/threadsjson.jsp")
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(result => {
     console.log(result)
  })
```